# Rails 3 Routes: Override Topics#show with Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Pretty simple question, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this, even after scouring the Rails Routing guide.

Assume Topics has nested resource Posts.

The Posts for a Topic are all listed in Posts#index (`/topics/:topic_id/messages`). Topics#show does not serve any purpose. I would like Posts#index to be retrieved when the request is for `/topics/:topic_id`, without having to stick a redirect in the Topics controller.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the desired result with this:

**routes.rb**

```
match 'forums/:forum_id' => 'topics#index', :as => 'forum_topics', :via => :get
match 'topics/:topic_id' => 'messages#index', :as => 'topic_messages', :via => :get

resources :forums, :shallow => true, :except => :show do
  resources :topics, :shallow => true, :except => :show do
    resources :messages
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best method.

**UPDATE 2**
My method above breaks the other CRUD methods (like #create). Still looking for a solution to keep /messages out of the url.

Comment: how does your routes file look?

Comment: See my update. I solved the problem, but would still like to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this route

```
get "/topics/:topic_id" => redirect("/topics/%{topic_id}/messages")
```

**UPD**

without redirecting:

```
get "/topics/:id" => "topic::Messages#index"
```

Or, if you're using `shallow`:

```
get "/topics/:id" => "messages#index"

resources :forums, :shallow => true, :except => :show do
  resources :topics, :shallow => true, :except => :show do
    resources :messages
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I was actually hoping that the `/messages` wouldn't be seen at all, as it's unnecessary URL information.

Comment: Using this: `get '/topics/:topic_id' => 'messages#index` does allow the path I'm looking for, but I would like this path (/topics/:topic_id) to be default when using the route helpers: `topic_messages_path(@topic)` for example. Adding `:as => 'topic_messages'` accomplished this, but then broke the other CRUD requests.

Comment: By the way I accepted your answer because you did answer the question I asked, now I'm just expanding on it.

Comment: you can use `:as => 'topic_messages'` here and it shouldn't break other methods because it is only about `GET`